# Evolute of a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

So, take $\alpha(t)=(R \cos t, R \sin t)$, its evolute is given by:

$c(s)= \alpha(s)+\kappa(s)N(s)$

Where the s means we've taken a reparametrization with its arc's lenght. Now I know $\kappa= \frac{1}{R}$ and that $\alpha(s)= R(\cos(\frac{s}{R}), \sin(\frac{s}{R}))$, this gives us $N=-(\cos(\frac{s}{R}), \sin(\frac{s}{R}))$

So we will get that the evolute of the circle is:

$\frac{R^2-1}{R}(\cos(\frac{s}{R}), \sin(\frac{s}{R}))$
But the evolute of a circle centered at the origin should be (0,0), what am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: The evolute is $c(s)=\alpha(s)+\rho(s)N(s)$ with $\rho=1/\kappa$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and then I get zero always! Thank you.